# How to convert a hashmap to csv file in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am currently creating an app where I create a csv file via hashmap in kotlin. My current hashmap looks like this:

val savehash:MutableMap<String, MutableList> = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList>()

{(a1 = [124,125,125,128.....]),(b1 = [121,125,126,124,129....])}

I would like to have each key be the column with each element of the list becoming the column values(rows). How would I convert this into Kotlin?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: what exactly doesn't work or what do you not know how to do? How to spread the map into the components? Or how to create the file? Also, how do you want the values to look like? `1,2,3,4` or `[1,2,3,4]` or etc?

Comment: Hi, I dont know how as I am very new to kotlin. I am uncertain how to spread the map into components. I want my values to look like 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

You can go with pure Kotlin if values in your list doesn't include `valuesSeparator` (comma) and `lineTerminator` (CRLF) symbols (in that case you'd better use some libraries, like [commons-csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/), which will handle escaping symbols for you):

```kotlin
val csv = File("path\\to\\your\\csv\\output\\file")
val valuesSeparator = ","
val lineTerminator = "\r\n"
//write header, overwrite file if it has existed
csv.writeText(savehash.keys.joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator))
//write rows
val nRows =
//  savehash.values.first().size        // if it's guaranteed that size of all lists is the same
    savehash.values.maxOf { it.size }   // otherwise
for (i in 0 until nRows) {
    val row = savehash.values
        // .map { it[i] }               // if it's guaranteed that size of all lists is the same
        .map { it.getOrElse(i) { "" } } // otherwise
        .joinToString(separator = valuesSeparator, postfix = lineTerminator)
    csv.appendText(row)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much sir! You are amazing!

Comment: Out of curiousity, How should i set up my path for File if i want to save it locally on my android phone?

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific

Comment: hi! Do I need to already have a empty file in the path in order to have it write? I am sorry, I looked at the URL that you gave me but I am having trouble saving the csv

Comment: Not an expert in Android development, but on desktop, it's not mandatory - if a file doesn't exist it would be created automatically (unless there are some OS security restrictions). Feel free to ask a new question about file creation on Android in general - probably somebody with bigger expertise in Android development, could answer it